# How to send data from Server to multiple Clients using Sockets?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client, server

I have simple server-clients programm:

```
public class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket server;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            this.server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("New server initialized!");
            this.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostName()
                        + " connected");
                new ServerHandler(client);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server handler must send message in stream:

```
public class ServerHandler extends Thread {
    protected Socket client;
    protected String userInput;
    protected PrintWriter out;
    protected BufferedReader console;

    public ServerHandler(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.userInput = null;
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("New Communication Thread Started");
        System.out.println("Enter message:");
        try {
            this.out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            this.console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while ((this.userInput = console.readLine()) != null) {
                this.out.println(userInput);
            }               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side receives that message :

```
public class Client {
    protected Socket client;
    protected BufferedReader in;

    public Client(String hostName, int ip) {
        try {
            this.client = new Socket(hostName, ip);
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.client.getInputStream()));
            String buffer = null;
            while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(buffer);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It works well with one client,but when I start new client problem with receiving message from server arises.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but in your Server class you create a new instance of ServerHandler but you don't assign it to anything.  With nothing referencing it it can be garbage collected at any time.

Comment: you need in your server an arraylist of socket connections. put each client on a thread and then create a thread in your server that sends data to your clients. make sure you `synchronize` on your arraylist tho

Comment: @JohnSheridan That's not correct. It extends Thread, and its constructor calls start(), so it isn't elegible for GC until it exits.

Comment: @EJP You're absolutely right.  Must have been sleepwalking.  Forgot that a running Thread is treated as a GC root and immune from GC.  Thanks for picking this up.

Comment: Changed my code but still have problem.Read my answer below please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
public class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket server;
    protected List<ClientHandler> clients;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            this.server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("New server initialized!");
            clients = Collections
                    .synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ClientHandler>());
            this.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostName()
                        + " connected");
                ClientHandler newClient = new ClientHandler(client);
                clients.add(newClient);
                new SendMessage(clients);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientHandler instead of Serverhandler class:

```
public class ClientHandler {
    protected Socket client;
    protected PrintWriter out;

    public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
        try {
            this.out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thread can be added to Client class but works fine without it.I assume because when main method called new thread automatically created:

```
public class Client {
    protected Socket client;
    protected BufferedReader in;

    public Client(String hostName, int ip) {
        try {
            this.client = new Socket(hostName, ip);
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.client.getInputStream()));
            String buffer = null;
            while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(buffer);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Class that sends data to clients:

```
 public class SendMessage extends Thread {
        protected List<ClientHandler> clients;
        protected String userInput;
        protected BufferedReader console;

        public SendMessage(List<ClientHandler> clients) {
            this.clients = clients;
            this.userInput = null;
            this.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("New Communication Thread Started");
            if (clients.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter message:");
            }
            try {
                if (clients.size() > 0) {
                    this.console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            System.in));
                    while ((this.userInput = console.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (userInput != null & userInput.length() > 0) {
                            for (ClientHandler client : clients) {
                                client.out.println(userInput);
                                client.out.flush();
                            Thread.currentThread();
                            Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it works!
Need to make SendMessage thread sleep after flushing data.
Main for server starter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Server(1200);
}
```

Main for client starter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Client("127.233.0.1", 1200);
}
```

Comment: If anyone needs working version I can give bitbucket link

Comment: Did it long time ago. Here is the link